# static member variable file scope

Tags: c++

Static variable has the scope inside that file only where they are been declared, as shown in below code:

file1-

```
static int a;
```

file2-

```
extern int a;
```

This will give linking error as static variable a has the scope in file1 only.  But I am confused with below code:

file2-

```
#include "file1"
extern int a;
```

Here it would not give any linking error. Then it means compiler is refering "a" which is declared in file1. But when you debug you will find address of variable "a" is different in file1 and file2. Is the compiler creating a another global variable "a" in file2?

complete code-

file temp1.h -

```
static int w = 9;

class temp1 
{
public:
   temp1(void);
public:
   ~temp1(void);

   void func();

};
```

........................cpp.................

```
temp1::temp1(void)
{
   int e =w;
}

temp1::~temp1(void)
{
}
void temp1::func()
{
}
```

.......................................
file2-

```
#include "temp1.h"

extern int w;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   w  = 12;

   temp1 obj;
   return 0;
}
```

here when i debug and check the value and adrress in temp1 constructor and in file2 is different.

Comment: Unless `temp1.h` is including itself, that code isn't complete (or possibly isn't correct). Can you show the contents of `temp1.h`?

Comment: Post edit, I think my answer fully answers your question. In both translation units `w` has _internal linkage_ due to the first declaration of `w` being the `static int w = 9;` declaration included from the header file. This mean that both translation units have their own distinct independent `w`.

Comment: So it means second translation unit also define the variable w even it was extern (as it would not cause redefinition because first definition was internal linkage in translation unit 1)?

Comment: Yes, a declaration of an object marked `extern` without an initializer is never a definition. If the object has previously been declared then the linkage is taken from the previous declaration (in this case internal), if no previous declaration exist then the object has external linkage. The only _definition_ in both translation units comes from the `static` declaration in the header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file1:

```
static int a;
```

file2:

```
extern int a;
```

There are two variables referenced here. The first is a declaration and definition of a variable with *internal linkage* in `file1`; the second is a declaration only of a variable with *external linkage* in `file2`. This doesn't necessarily cause an error; it is completely legal to have a variable with external linkage used in some translation units and identically named variables with internal linkage used by other translation units. Any link error would only occur if `a` is used in `file2` and there isn't a definition for this `a` in `file2` or any other translation unit in the program.

```
#include "file1"
extern int a;
```

In this example you have combined the two files into a single translation unit. The variable `a` is first declared and defined in `file` with *internal linkage* due to `static`, the second is just a re-declaration which doesn't alter the previous linkage. The second declaration is redundant in this instance. If you are still compiling both files separately as well as including `file1` from `file2` then each translation unit (`file1` and `file1 + file2`) will have its own distinct variable called `a`.

Note that if you had used `extern int a;` followed by `static int a;` then this would be a compile error as the first declaration would declare `a` to have *external linkage* if no previously declaration was visible and then the second declaration and definition would cause an error because the linkage implied by `static int a;` would conflict with the previous declaration.

Comment: Now this make sense for me. Thanks Charles for clarification.

Answer (score 7):

`static` and `extern` are not to do with *files*, they're to do with *translation units*.  Remember that when you `#include` something, the preprocessor is effectively doing a copy-and-paste.  `static`, etc. refer to the result of that process, which is a translation unit.

So in your second example, there is only one translation unit.  So there is only one variable `a`.  *[But note, doing it this way is considered very bad style.]*

Comment: yes, this is one translation unit. but why address of varaibale "a" is different in both files?

Comment: @Ghanshyam: I think you'd have to edit your question to show a *complete*, *compilable* example to show what you mean.

Comment: @Ghanshyam: That has nothing to do with the *address of variables*.  Please *edit you original question* with some code!